# How to change variable in gitlab cicd pipeline depending on branch

Tags: gitlab-ci

I need to call a bash script from my gitlab cicd pipeline. When I call it, the input parameter needs to change depending on whether or not this is a merge into master. Basically what I want is this:

if master:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - INPUT="foo"
  - $(myscript.sh $INPUT)
```

if NOT master:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - INPUT=""
  - $(myscript.sh $INPUT)
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to set INPUT depending on which branch the pipeline is running on. I know there are rules as well as only/except, but they don't seem to allow you to set variable, only test them. I know the brute force way is to just write this twice, one with "only master" and another with "except master", but I would really like to avoid that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have two jobs to run the script and use rules to control when they are ran against master:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - if [$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == 'master']; then export INPUT="foo"; else INPUT=""; fi
  - $(myscript.sh $INPUT)
```

Comment: That's what I was hoping to avoid. If that's the only real way to do it, then I'll do it that way though.

Comment: Sorry I didn’t think of this before, why don’t you set up a conditional in the script to set the “INPUT” variable. The conditional being a if else check for $CI_BUILD_REF_NAME.

Comment: I have updated the answer so this can be accomplished with one job.

Comment: It looks like part of the problem was that $CI_BUILD_REF_NAME was changed to $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME ( https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/deprecated_variables.html ). Your solution is basically what I originally thought would work, but I think the problem was that I was using the wrong variables for my checks.

Answer (score 2):

I implement this kind of thing using yml anchors to extend tasks.

I find it easier to read and customization can include other things, not only variables.

For example:

```
.test_my_software:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo ${MESSAGE}
    - bash test.sh

test stable:
  <<: *test_my_software
  variables:
    MESSAGE: testing stable code!
  only:
    - /stable.*/

test:
  <<: *test_my_software
  variables:
    MESSAGE: testing our code!
  except:
    - /stable.*/
```

you get the idea...